# How do you dissasociate a single file in a VS2010 project which is under source control from source control iteself?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

We have a project (C#) which has been added to source control (TFS 2010), however one of the project files is anauto generated one and as such we dont want it under source control.

Is there a way to remove the source control association for this single file in the project?

Please note the autogenerated file is made from a custom XML document using an internal standalone tool.  Whilst I appreciate a long term solution to this issue would be to not have the file linked to the project, but to include the source XML document and have it associated with an appropriate custom tool to generate the C# file at build time.  Sadly creating said custom tool is not going to happen in my immediate future hence the query about dissacociating the generated file that is in the project from the projects TFS source control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up the project and select the file.

On the VS menu go to: File -> Source Control -> Exclude FILE_NAME From Source Control

Comment: Excellent. Obvious really.  I was worring this want possible as I had been looking for a similar option in the context menu of the solution explorer.

Comment: Interesting side note; the "Exclude xx.cs from source control" menu is populated *ONLY* when the file was added to the project. NOT if it was *LINKED*.  Not sure why this would make a difference but it seems it does.